# Setting up a mass timer in php

Tags: php, timer

So i have a few sites with a timer on when it gets to 0 it does something but my next project is a market place website were users can bid on items im getting a bit stuck with the timer on my current projects the user stays on the page the timer goes to 0 then they get what they wanted of course on the auction site if users are not viewing the page ( sat ion the page ) my timer wont go down. And im guessing a cron job every second will kill my server. I understand the users adds the item and the date and time is added then i can set the end time and add that but havn't any ideas were to go from there here is my time

```
<?php
$random_word = preg_replace('/([ ])/e', 'chr(rand(97,122))', '     ');

$timer = '26';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Check if the page has loaded completely                                         
$(document).ready( function() { 
    setTimeout( function() { 
$('#some_id').load('http://mydomainname.com/parser.php'); 
    }, 23000); 
}); 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout("location.href='surf.php?id=<?php echo $random_word ; ?>'", 26000);
});
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: You can to store the timers for each item (along with other info) as rows in a database table.  Your server probably has MySQL.

Comment: Yes i can do that easily so i just store the date and time the item has been added then maybe add 24 hours onto it store that has the end time then on the item page show the time and date which it ends for that item then when it gets under  lets say 1 hour i do a if stament if under 1 hour i show a timer on page ? The bids is tricky i guess i have a table for bids then just do any bids after x time doesnt count ?? But then if 2 ppl bid at same time??

Comment: give javascript time to the end by php, update timer by javascript `setTimeout` every second, if you need meanwhile check if someone change value in php do ajax request. use transaction in sql to be sure which one of 2 ppl was first